# Print a string a number of times

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, sed, awk

I have a variable `numvar` which contains a number.

**CODE**

```
            something that reads number stored in numvar and then creates the same number of sTrapValue[with a number here that incrementally increases with each print from 0 to numvar]
```

**INPUT**

```
echo $numvar
5
```

I am to create `$numvar`times printed `sTrapValue[x]`, where `x` is a incrementally increasing number.

**OUTPUT**
Into Another variable  `bl`

```
echo $bl
sTrapValue[0],sTrapValue[1],sTrapValue[2],sTrapValue[3],sTrapValue[4],sTrapValue[5].
```

All of them have a comma only the last sTrapValue[] ends with a .(fullstop)

Any command to do this Grep/sed/awk?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. What is your "code" supposed to be? Why is it in a code block if it isn't code? That just makes it harder to read. Show us your _actual_ code and the exact output you'd like to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```bsh
$ numvar=5

$ bl="$(seq 0 "$numvar" | while read i; do echo "sTrapValue[$i]"; done) \
bl="${bl//$'\n'/,}" && bl="$(sed 's/$/./' <<<"$bl")"
```

It has three parts:

- `seq 0 "$numvar" | while read i; do echo "sTrapValue[$i]"; done` will generate a newline separated output showing entries `sTrapValue[0-5]`.
- `"${bl//$'\n'/,}"` will convert all newlines to commas.
- `$(sed 's/$/./' <<<"$bl")` will add a `.` at the end.

You can also use `tr` and `sed` to format the output:

```
 bl="$(seq 0 "$numvar" | while read i; do echo "sTrapValue[$i]"; done | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$/./')"
```

**Test :**

```
$ echo "$bl"
sTrapValue[0],sTrapValue[1],sTrapValue[2],sTrapValue[3],sTrapValue[4],sTrapValue[5].
```

Comment: No, no. Have a look at my output. That's how I want to print/stored in `bl`. whatever number `numvar` contains thats how many times `sTrapValue` will be printed.

Comment: @SamFlynn Check my edited answer.....

Answer (score 1):

```
sTrapValue[0]='a'; 
sTrapValue[1]='b'; 
sTrapValue[2]='c'; 
numvar=2; 
COUNTER=0; 
BL=""; 
while [ ! $COUNTER -gt ${numvar} ]; do 
  BL=${BL}${sTrapValue[$COUNTER]},; 
  let COUNTER=COUNTER+1; 
done; 
BL=$(echo ${BL} | sed 's/,$/./'); 
echo $BL;
```

=> a,b,c.

**EDIT :**

Answer to the edited question:

```
numvar=2; 
COUNTER=0; 
BL=""; 
while [ ! $COUNTER -gt ${numvar} ]; do 
  BL=${BL}sTrapValue[${COUNTER}],; 
  let COUNTER=COUNTER+1; 
done; 
BL=$(echo ${BL} | sed 's/,$/./'); 
echo $BL;
```

=> sTrapValue[0],sTrapValue[1],sTrapValue[2].

Comment: No, no. Have a look at my output. That's how I want to print/stored in `bl`. whatever number `numvar` contains thats how many times `sTrapValue` will be printed.

Comment: numvar=5  but your array goes from 0-5, that's 6 values in your output that you wanted.

Comment: yes the array goes from 0-6. so `sTrapValue[0],sTrapValue[1],sTrapValue[2],sTrapValue[3],sTrapValue[4],sTrapValue[5].`   this is what output will be.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for something like:

```
$ printf 'sTrapValue[%s],' $(seq 0 $numvar) | sed 's/,$/.\n/'
sTrapValue[0],sTrapValue[1],sTrapValue[2],sTrapValue[3],sTrapValue[4],sTrapValue[5].
```